# Get percentage of returned row values

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, percentage

Looking to get the percentage value for each of the "task_types". Looked at many examples but can't quite figure it out. I tried putting the statement below into another SELECT statement to try to divide, but it would always have SQL errors. Any ideas?

Here's SQL:

```
SELECT t.task_type, (SUM(trktm.time_end) - SUM(trktm.time_start)) as thetime
   FROM
   task as t, track_time as trktm
   WHERE
   trktm.time_start BETWEEN 1593932400 AND 1594450800
   AND
   trktm.time_end BETWEEN 1593932400 AND 1594450800
   AND
   t.user_id = 10
   GROUP BY t.task_type
   ORDER BY FIELD(t.task_type, 'Unassigned') DESC, t.task_type ASC
```

Here's the output:

```
task_type   |  thetime
- - - - - - - - - - - - - -         
Unassigned  |  1041078
Bug Fixes   |  694052
Design      |  347026
```

But here's what I'm trying to achieve:

```
task_type   |  thetime   |   thepercent
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -         
Unassigned  |  1041078   |   70.4
Bug Fixes   |  694052    |   19.6
Design      |  347026    |   10.0
```

Comment: Please explain the background behind the expected `thepercent` column.

Comment: Specify MySQL version. It is important in your task. *But here's what I'm trying to achieve* Calculate total sum in separate subquery or CTE and divide.

Comment: Pls mention the total count to find out the percentage like --- select  (thetime * 100 / (total No of Employe)) as Percentage

Comment: I found it quit obvious that the percentage of the totaltime is wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The straightahaed solution: Join with the totaltime

```
SELECT taskt_type, thetime, (thetime/totaltime) * 100 as thepercent From 
  (SELECT t.task_type, (SUM(trktm.time_end) - SUM(trktm.time_start)) as thetime
     FROM
       task as t, track_time as trktm
     WHERE
       trktm.time_start BETWEEN 1593932400 AND 1594450800
     AND
       trktm.time_end BETWEEN 1593932400 AND 1594450800
     AND
      t.user_id = 10
   GROUP BY t.task_type) A
JOIN 
  (SELECT  (SUM(trktm.time_end) - SUM(trktm.time_start)) as totaltime
     FROM
       task as t, track_time as trktm
     WHERE
       trktm.time_start BETWEEN 1593932400 AND 1594450800
     AND
       trktm.time_end BETWEEN 1593932400 AND 1594450800
     AND
      t.user_id = 10
   ) B
ORDER BY FIELD(task_type, 'Unassigned') DESC, task_type ASC
```